# Any reasons to disable caching when all database access is performed via JPA?

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA 2.1 implemented by EclipseLink 2.5.2.

I would like to improve performance by caching `@Entity`s using `@Cacheable`.

My code is the only code that accesses the database.

All of my code's database access is performed via JPA calls.

My code runs on multiple GlassFish 4.1 instances with JPA JMS cache coordination enabled.

As long as I'm ok with servers possibly using old data from a cache for the incredibly short while that it takes for updates to be propagated via cache coordination, are there any reasons to disable caching of a JPA entity?

I also would like to cache query results using `eclipselink.query-results-cache`.  In this situation, are there any reasons to disable such caching?

Thanks.

Comment: There is overhead in maintaining a cache that at some ratio of writes to reads starts to hurt performance more than what using the cache for reads might gain.  The cache is recommended for the majority of use cases, but only performance metrics can really tell you how much you gain or lose by using it, and if your app is using it effectively.  If your app is tolerant of occasional stale data, caching is a great help for read mostly data.

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain that EclipseLink enables the L2 cache by default so adding `@Cacheable` won't show a performance improvement.

Comment: Exactly right Rick - I'd add that using eclipselink.query-results-cache WILL give you stale data, since it is not flushed as the object cache is when transactional updates are made (you will need to choose invalidation parameters based on your application's needs). Have a read here for more information: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache#Query_Results_Cache